# Why can't my Typescript file import json when using paths in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

I'm trying to resolve an issue where this line produces an error:

```
import Rush from '@mocks/rush.json';
```

Error:

> Cannot find module '@mocks/rush.json'. Consider using
> '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.

So I used that suggestion and updated my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "paths": {
            "@mocks/*": ["../mocks/*"],
            "@root/*": ["../*"],
            "@src/*": ["./*"]
        },
    },
}
```

Why would I be getting that error? The path locations seem to be correct and the file does exist.

If I don't use the @ symbol, it works:

```
import Rush from '../../mocks/rush.json';
```

I was able to get it to compile by adding this to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
```

However, I still get this error in my Mocha Test Explorer:

> Cannot find module '@mocks/rush.json'